# function ifelse calculation

Tags: r, function

I am trying to write the function in R, but keep getting an error. Within 1 simulation run I generate random values from 2 intevals - in order to generate 2 different output values.

- se.m if the input parameter lies within [0, 1]
- se.st if the input parameter lies wiothin [1, 5]

(floating point in neglegible)

Then, these randomly generated values are used as input in the following function:

[image]

This is the code I have used:

```
fuchs08 <- function(n){
  x.m=se.m=x.st=se.st=NULL 
  for(i in 1:n){
    se.m[i] <- ifelse (runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1) < 0.33, 0, 0.12 * (x.m[i]^2) - 0.04 * x.m[i])
    se.st[i] <- ifelse (runif(n = 1, min = 1, max = 5) < 3.06, 0.12 * (x.m[i]^2) - 0.04 * x.m[i], 1)
  }
  return(cbind(se.m, se.st))
}
```

I dont get any results. I believe the error is in the ifelse statement, but cannot find a solution to it.

```
> fuchs08(5)
     se.m se.st
[1,]    0    NA
[2,]   NA     1
[3,]   NA     1
[4,]   NA    NA
[5,]    0     1
```

The overall idea is add this function to a list of functions called `funktionen`. Then I run a simulation 100 times. Simulation 1 randomly chooses a function from the list `funktionen` and executes it. (Function creates two outputs for the aforementioned intevals: `se.m` and `se.st` which are combined with the outputs from simulation 2:99) Therefore the function needs to be in the format: `function(n)` in order to run the random function selection. Here is my code for that part:

```
funktionen <- list(akbas, bell.glade, borter, fell.hartford, fuchs07, fuchs08)

fxn_list_sample <- sample(1:5, 100, replace=T)
fxn_list_result <- unlist(sapply(fxn_list_sample, function(x) do.call(funktionen[[x]], args=list(n=1))))
results <- as.data.frame(t(fxn_list_result))
colnames(results) <- c("se.m", "se.st")
results <- melt(results)
results$value <-round(results$value, 4)
separate(results, variable, into = c("Parameter", "Intensitaet")) %>%
  mutate(Intensitaet = c(3, 2) [(Intensitaet == "m")+1])
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: I’m not surprised — your `x.m` is empty, of course accessing it will not yield appropriate values. I’m also not sure why you’re using `ifelse`, which is already vectorised, inside a loop. This feels redundant but I may simply be misunderstanding your requirements.

Comment: @Konrad thank you for your input. Indeed, I am not sure i have explained myself very well. Therefore I edited the question. To your question why i used a loop that seems rebundant? I have used the same procedure for the other functions (not shown here) that end up in the list `funktionen`. I basically didn't know any better...

Answer (score 2):

To answer your trouble with `ifelse()`:
`ifelse()` needs three arguments to make sense (condition, yes, no). it works with only the condition if the condition evaluates to NA, hence the NA's in your results and works with two arguments if the condition evalutates to TRUE, hence the 1 in your resutls. As Konrad says in the comment, the use of ifelse seems redundant. For illustration:

```
> ifelse(1==1)
Error in ifelse(1 == 1) : argument "yes" is missing, with no default

> ifelse(NA)
[1] NA

> ifelse(1==1, 4)
[1] 4

> ifelse(1!=1, 4)
Error in ifelse(1 != 1, 4) : argument "no" is missing, with no default

> ifelse(1!=1, 4, 10)
[1] 10
```

Regarding your original problem, I am not sure if I understand you question correctly, but maybe this does what you want:

```
fuchs08 <- function(x){
ifelse(x<1/3, 0,
       ifelse(x<=3.06, 0.12*x^2-0.04*x, 1))
}

fuchs08_with_n_inputs_two_outputcols <- function(n) {
df <- data.frame(input=runif(n, 0, 5))
df$se.m <- ifelse(df$input<1, fuchs08(df$input), NA)
df$se.st <- ifelse(df$input>1 & df$input<5, fuchs08(df$input), NA)
return(df)
}

fuchs08_with_n_inputs_two_outputcols(10)
```

Edit: replaced `n` by `x` to avoid confusion and added a second function after having read your answer (the name is long for the sake of clarity...). It is not the output in your answer but may easily be transformed to that. I think it would be helpfull to give an example of the output you want and which format it should have (data.frame, named vector...?)

Comment: Thank you @yoland, this would work. But i run it and only get NA values for the se.m?

Comment: If you remove the NA's it should be the same you posted. From your question i concluded that se.m should not be defined if the input is greater than 1, hence the NA's.

Answer (score 0):

I think ifelse & if-and-else are both awkward. You could try something like:

```
fuchs08<-function(n,min,max) {
  x<-runif(n,min,max)
  y<-x
  y[x<1/3]<-0
  y[x>=1/3 & x<=3.06]<-0.12*y[x>=1/3 & x<=3.06]^2-0.04*y[x>=1/3 & x<=3.06]
  y[x>3.06]<-1
  return(y)
}

(want<-cbind(fuchs08(100,0,1),fuchs08(100,1,5)))
```

Comment: Unfortnatelly this wouldn't work in the context of my problem, which you couldn't have know. This function is one of many that descibe the same process. From the list of all my functions i randomlly choose one and run it. I do this x times. All my functions are in format of `function(n)`The command to randomly choose is: `fxn_list_sample <- sample(1:5, 100, replace=T)
fxn_list_result <- unlist(sapply(fxn_list_sample, function(x) do.call(funktionen[[x]], args=list(n=1))))
`. Unfortunatelly the command wouldn't run on your function `function(n,min,max)`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. However, not very elegant answer. Feel free to give me tipps to improve it, reduce rebundant elements, etc.

```
fuchs08 <- function(n) {
  x.m=se.m=x.st=se.st=NULL 
  for(i in 1:n){
    print(x.m[i] <- runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1))
    se.m[i] <- ifelse (runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1) < 0.33, 0, 0.12 * x.m[i]^2 - 0.04* x.m[i])
    print(x.st[i] <- runif(n = 1, min = 1, max = 5))
    se.st[i] <- ifelse (runif(n = 1, min = 1, max = 5) < 3.06, 0.12 * x.st[i]^2 - 0.04* x.st[i], 1)
  }
  return(cbind(se.m, se.st))
}
fuchs08(10)
```

The whole code is:

```
library(reshape2)
library(stringr)
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("tidyr")
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)

# AKBAS u.a. (2009)
akbas <- function(n){
  x.m=se.m=x.st=se.st=NULL 
  for(i in 1:n){
    print(x.m[i] <- runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1))
    se.m[i] <- 0.17 * (x.m[i]^2) - 0.03 * x.m[i]
    print(x.st[i] <- runif(n = 1, min = 1, max = 5))
    se.st[i] <- 0.17 * (x.st[i]^2) - 0.03 * x.st[i]
  }
  akbasr<-return(cbind(se.m, se.st))
}

# FUCHS u.a.(2007)
fuchs07 <- function(n){
  x.m=se.m=x.st=se.st=NULL #solves indexing problem
  for(i in 1:n){
    print(x.m[i] <- runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1))
    se.m[i] <- 0.11 * (x.m[i]^2) - 0.02 * x.m[i]
    print(x.st[i] <- runif(n = 1, min = 1, max = 5))
    se.st[i] <- 0.11 * (x.st[i]^2) - 0.02 * x.st[i]
  }
  return(cbind(se.m, se.st))
}

# BELL AND GLADE (2004)
bell.glade <- function(n){
  x.m=se.m=x.st=se.st=NULL 
  for(i in 1:n){
    se.m[i] <- ifelse (runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1) < 1, 0.2, 0.2)
    se.st[i] <- ifelse (runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1) < 1, 0.5, 0.5)
  }
  return(cbind(se.m, se.st))
}

# BORTER (1999b,a)
borter <- function(n){
  x.m=se.m=x.st=se.st=NULL 
  for(i in 1:n){
    se.m[i] <- ifelse (runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1) < 1, 0.1, 0.1)
    se.st[i] <- ifelse (runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1) < 1, 0.5, 0.5)
  }
  return(cbind(se.m, se.st))
}

# FELL UND HARTFORD (1997)
fell.hartford <- function(n){
  x.m=se.m=x.st=se.st=NULL 
  for(i in 1:n){
    se.m[i] <- ifelse (runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1) < 0.25, 0.1, 0.4)
    se.st[i] <- ifelse (runif(n = 1, min = 1, max = 5) < 1.5, 0.4, 0.7)
  }
  return(cbind(se.m, se.st))
}


# FUCH (2008, 2009)
fuchs08 <- function(n) {
  x.m=se.m=x.st=se.st=NULL 
  for(i in 1:n){
    print(x.m[i] <- runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1))
    se.m[i] <- ifelse (runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = 1) < 0.33, 0, 0.12 * x.m[i]^2 - 0.04* x.m[i])
    print(x.st[i] <- runif(n = 1, min = 1, max = 5))
    se.st[i] <- ifelse (runif(n = 1, min = 1, max = 5) < 3.06, 0.12 * x.st[i]^2 - 0.04* x.st[i], 1)
  }
  return(cbind(se.m, se.st))
}

funktionen <- list(akbas, bell.glade, borter, fell.hartford, fuchs07, fuchs08)

fxn_list_sample <- sample(1:5, 100, replace=T)
fxn_list_result <- unlist(sapply(fxn_list_sample, function(x) do.call(funktionen[[x]], args=list(n=1))))
results <- as.data.frame(t(fxn_list_result))
colnames(results) <- c("se.m", "se.st")
results <- melt(results)
results$value <-round(results$value, 4)
separate(results, variable, into = c("Parameter", "Intensitaet")) %>%
  mutate(Intensitaet = c(3, 2) [(Intensitaet == "m")+1])

write.csv(results, "murgang-test.csv")
```